# Surface integral of pressure for quasi-1D flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, integration

**Background**

Suppose you have quasi-1D flow, as shown in the figure below taken from *Modern Compressible Flow* by John Anderson.

[image]

Anderson writes that the momentum equation for inviscid, steady flow with no body forces

$$
\iint_S (\rho\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{S})\mathbf{V}+\iiint_\mathscr{V}\frac{\partial (\rho\mathbf{V})}{\partial t}d\mathscr{V}=\iiint_\mathscr{V}\rho\mathbf{f}d\mathscr{V}-\iint_Spd\mathbf{S}
$$

applied to the case shown in the figure yields

$$
p_1A_1+\rho_1u_1^2A_1+\int_{A_1}^{A_2}pdA=p_2A_2+\rho_2u_2^2A_2
$$

**Question**

My question is about the term $\int_{A_1}^{A_2}pdA$. I want to write a step-by-step and detailed proof showing that

$$
\iint_Spd\mathbf{S}
=-p_1A_1+p_2A_2+\int_{A_1}^{A_2}pdA
$$

- Do you have a clean proof for this?
- Or, can you help clean up my proof?

**Attempt**

I want find an expression for $\iint_Spd\mathbf{S}$.

\begin{align}
\iint_Spd\mathbf{S}&=-p_1A_1+p_2A_2+\iint_{LS}pd\mathbf{S}
\end{align}

Let coordinate axes be defined such that the xy-plane is in the screen and the x-axis is along the centerline axis of the tube.

[image]

The thrust of my approach is to express the lateral surface integral as a double integral $\iint_{LS}pd\mathbf{S}$ with respect to $x$ and $\phi$, where $\phi$ is the angle from the y-axis to the projection of the surface normal vector in the yz-plane.

First, consider the surface normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, where $d\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{n}dS$ and dS is a differential surface area element. Then
$$
\mathbf{n}=(n_x,n_y,n_z)
$$

for an arbitrary differential element on the surface of the tube. However, looking at a differential surface area element with a normal vector that is in the xy-plane, we can draw the following figure.

[image]

For any other surface element inclined at an angle $\phi$ but at the same $x$ location, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{n}&=(n_x,n_y\cos\phi,n_y\sin\phi)\\
&=(\sin\theta,\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi)
\end{align*}

Strictly speaking, $\theta=\theta(x)$, and the precise relationship defines the tube geometry. However, knowing this relationship isn't necessary as long as $\theta$ does not depend on $\phi$.

At this point, the integral can be written
$$
\iint_{LS}pd\mathbf{S}=\int\int p(x)(\sin\theta,\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi) dS
$$

Express the differential area $dS$ now as a slice subtended by the angle $d\phi$ on the truncated frustum of total area $dS_{TF}$.

[image]

The lateral [surface area of a truncated frustum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFrustum.html#:%7E:text=Conical%20Frustum.%20A%20conical%20frustum%20is%20a%20frustum,of%20the%20top%20and%20bottom%20of%20the%20frustum.) is

\begin{align*}
dS_{TF}&=\pi dl (r+(r+dr))\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}(2\pi rdr + \pi dr^2)
\end{align*}

where $dl=dr/\sin(\theta)$ is the differential slant height. Note that $dA=d(\pi r^2)=2\pi r dr$. Taking $dr^2\approx 0$, we have

$$
dS=\frac{d\phi}{2\pi}\frac{dA}{\sin(\theta)}
$$

Thus we can write

\begin{align*}
\iint_{LS}pd\mathbf{S}&=\int\int p(x)(\sin\theta,\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi) dS\\
&=\int_{A_1}^{A_2}\int_0^{2\pi} p (\sin\theta,\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi)\frac{d\phi}{2\pi}\frac{dA}{\sin\theta}\\
&=\int_{A_1}^{A_2} p (1,0,0)dA\\
&=\hat{\imath} \int_{A_1}^{A_2} p dA
\end{align*}

Well, that was a long argument. What do I want from all this? If you can point out any mistakes, I'd greatly appreciate it. If you have a more concise, cleaner, or more formal proof, I'd love to see it. I'm self-studying this material and trying to prove to myself that I can actually do the integrals.

Comment: Have you tried it using cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: I haven't... and I should! I will report back.